# Fuzzy Bit Matching

Tags: algorithm, fuzzy-search

I have a very long sequence of bits, called `A`, and a shorter sequence of bits, `x`. Two bit sequences of the same length are fuzzy-matched when after aligning them, there are `k` or fewer mismatched bits. I want to find all such fuzzy occurrences of x within A.

So far, I've tried the naive approach. Loop through A, then for each bit, loop through the length of x, count the number of mismatched bits starting at that position in A, and if it doesn't exceed k, report that position. This algorithm is not efficient. If A has n_A bits, and x has n_x bits, the running time is `O(n_A * n_x)`.

I'm told that this can be done in `O(n_A * log(n_A))` regardless of `k`. The hint provided is to make use of fast Fourier transform. Remember that for two inputs [image] and [image], convolution produces [image] where

[image: qqn]

similar to polynomial multiplication. It's not clear to me how to use this hint. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: test...........

Comment: test comment...........

Answer (score 4):

Reverse x, replace each bit b by (-1)**b, and convolve. I'll let you explain on your homework what to do next.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. It makes a lot of sense now :)

Comment: I think what you mean here is just to replace 0's with -1's. So in effect, we should replace bit b by -(-1)^b. But I got the problem solved using this trick. I'll post my own solution in a few days to explain why it works if no one answers.

Comment: Sorry to destroy your awesome score of `4444` but this is a good hint - and obviously worked for the OP.